# chrome extension insert text issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp

i wrote a chrome extension to change the content of intro class but it is not working??
i have created a division and inserted it before intro class
the code is written in content.js

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerText='test123';
document.getElementsByClassName("intro").insertBefore(div,document.getElementsByClassName("intro")childNodes[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. As such, it has no such method as `insertBefore`.

If you want to insert your div inside all elements of class `intro`, you can accomplish this via a loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("intro");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerText = 'test123';
    elements[i].insertBefore(div, elements[i].childNodes[0]);
}
```

Alternatively, if there is only one element, you can do:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerText = 'test123';
document.getElementsByClassName("intro")[0].insertBefore(div, document.getElementsByClassName("intro")[0].childNodes[0]);
```